# Building haskell platform 2014.2.0.0 on debian wheezy using locally-built ghc

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-install, ghc-pkg

I would like to install the latest release of the Haskell platform on Debian wheezy. By executing

```
 sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
```

I get `ghc` version 7.4.1 (released in 2012) whereas the current version is 7.8.3.

So I have downloaded the current `ghc` version source and built it: everything went fine and I can now execute `ghc`.
I then downloaded the source distribution of the Haskell platform from [here](http://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html#source) and in the `README` file I find the instructions

> ### REQUIREMENTS FOR BUILDING
>
> You need the platform build files, either from the *source repo* or the
>   *source tarball*.  Build instructions are the same for either.
>
> You need a GHC bindist that matches the OS you are compiling on. It
>   must also match the GHC version used by the platform, currently 7.8.3.
>   You can get this from:
>       http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_8_3

I actually do not want to use this, I would like to use the `ghc` I have just built because, in [the ghc documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_8_3#sources) I read:

> NOTE: If you have too old a version of libc, then you will get an
>   error like "floating point exception" from the binaries in these
>   bindists. You will need to either upgrade your libc (we're not sure
>   what the minimum version required is), or use a binary package built
>   for your distribution instead.

So, in order to be sure, I would prefer to use my build. But, the `README` that
comes with `haskell-platform-2014.2.0.0` does not say anything about such an option.
The only option that it offers is to run:

./platform.sh $PATH_TO_GHC_BINDIST_TARBALL

So: is there a way to build the Haskell platform using a `ghc` binary that I have built
locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Building and installing a system package](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#building-and-installing-a-system-package)

If you don't have a cabal binary (`which cabal`) you can build it from the platform packages.

- option 1: get it from your distribution `apt-get install cabal-install`
- option 2: build it from the platform packages, but you will need to build/install also the missing package dependencies, that must be present in the platform

`cd` to the platform base folder

```
cd packages/cabal-install-*

# compile Setup to run faster
ghc Setup.hs

./Setup configure --ghc
./Setup build
./Setup install
```

Then to install the rest

`cd` to the platform base folder

```
cabal configure --ghc 
cabal install
```

You may have to add `sudo` to install lines, depending on where you installed ghc

Comment: So the key is to use `--ghc` to check if there is an installed `ghc` in the path. However, `./Setup configure --ghc` says some dependences are not fulfilled: `HTTP >=4000.0.8 && <4001`, `mtl >=2.0 && <3`, `network >=1 && <3`, `random >=1 && <1.1`, `stm >=2.0 && <3`, `zlib >=0.5.3 && <0.6`.

Comment: BTW, I have managed to build platform `2013.2.0.0` (this version still contains a `configure` script which seems to work OK). Can I use this build to boot `2014.2.0.0` or will packages from both releases get mixed up?

Comment: Packages compiled with different ghc releases never mix. If you have installed an earlier platform you must have a cabal instance. You can go ahead without the --ghc flag anyway.

Comment: So I switch to the folder in which I have unpacked the 2014 release and do `cabal configure`, `cabal install` from there?

Comment: just `cabal install` suffices to do a user installation. Maybe you would better erase the user .ghc folder to make a clean one

Comment: It has worked but it is still not clear to me how this whole process works, and why the `configure` script that was available until release 2013 has been removed. In any case, thanks a lot for the directions!

Comment: I also long the configure version. I think that the easiest way to go with platform-2014-.. is to get a cabal executable binary from your linux distribution `apt-get install cabal-install` and `cabal install` the platform.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59878/discussion-between-giorgio-and-gabriel-riba).